# Facebook comments plugin - Post comment to profile link

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I use Facebook comments plugin for my Facebook Tab page.
Since the tab is located inside the facebook page, when user posts comment with checked option "Post comment on my Facebook profile", the link of this post on his wall leads to wrong url. 
I've created parser to navigate inside my tab using `app-data` and actively use it with `share` functional, but the question is - **Can I implement same behavior to the Facebook comments plugin to make posts with defined by me URLs, and how?**
Thanks.

At the moment, Facebook link from the wall that leads to comment looks like this ->

```
http://www.facebook.com/testexamplelala/posts/492870140724203
```

I wish to change it to something like this ->

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/testpage/id?sk=appid&amp;app_data={ here my data for parser }
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to work for me but maybe I'm doing something slightly different.  I have a FB Page. I add my FB App (that has the comments plugin) to my Page using the [Add Page Tab Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/). When I render the comments-plugin, I set the `data-href` attribute for the plugin:  `<div class="fb-comments" data-href="MY_URL" ... >`.  I load the Page, then load the tab, then add a comment with 'Post to Facebook' checked, and MY_URL is used in the story on the user's timeline/profile.